# Form should only accept PDF-file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I use the Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7 and allow users to upload a PDF-file.
The input field looks like this.

```
<input type="file" name="file-838" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file hidden" id="myFile" accept=".pdf" aria-invalid="false" />
```

On my computer and iPhone I can only upload a PDF-file, but on Samsung phones (and maybe other phones) people can upload an image which should not be possible.

What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Here's a note in mozilla details on `accept` :  It is still possible (in most cases) for users to toggle an option in the file chooser that makes it possible to override this and select any file they wish, and then choose incorrect file types.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept . In other words, a browser implementation can be expected to allow this override.

Comment: Also, check browser support: https://caniuse.com/input-file-accept